# Twilio call Status Callback return blank params

Tags: twilio

can someone help me with solving my problem?

I try to implement voice mail, I knew about tutorials about my problem, they were useful during building voice mail on first steps. 
I have endpoint for incoming calls, there I create response with dial TwiML for bind incoming call from SDK with call receiver. Below i will show you a TwiML example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial action="{{HOST}}/api/v1/voice_mails/start_recording" callerId="client:[client identity]" timeout="15">
        <Client>[Client identity]</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

the call happens, but if you wait 15 seconds + (5 seconds twillio adds) without answering, you get a request to record voicemail and call status callback, without "To" and "Called" params, they are blank.
There is example of `action="{{HOST}}/api/v1/voice_mails/start_recording"` request params below

```
ApplicationSid  "My Application Sid"
ApiVersion  "2010-04-01"
Called  ""
Caller  "client:[identity]"
DialCallSid "DialCallSid"
CallStatus  "in-progress"
CallSid "Call Sid"
To  ""
From    "client:[identity]"
DialCallStatus  "no-answer"
Direction   "inbound"
AccountSid  [My AccountSid]
```

May be it will useful: my client identity format is number without "+"
if phone number is "+1234567890" then identity will be "1234567890"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Hmm, that's interesting. I think this happens because, when you generate a call from a client the initial leg of the call doesn't have an idea of the `To`. Instead it requests TwiML from your TwiML application. In this case it gets a `<Dial>` but that's not necessary, therefore there's no `To` number that is intrinsic to the initial call itself.

We can work around this though. Instead of relying on the regular `To` field on the webhook for the record action, we can add it to the URL ourselves as a URL parameter.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial action="{{HOST}}/api/v1/voice_mails/start_recording?clientID=[client identity]" callerId="client:[client identity]" timeout="15">
        <Client>[Client identity]</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

You can then retrieve the client identity from the URL query parameters in the next action.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for not responding for a long time. Your advice is working. But status_callback only started working after I pointed to the action link directly in the `<Client>` tag and deleted it from my TwiML App, probably if you specify the TwiML App status callback url and not directly in the tag, then the behavior changes. And the recorder didn’t accept `Called` and `To` parameters, and I took your advice and indicated a custom query parameter. Below I will give a final example

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial action="{{HOST}}/api/v1/voice_mails/start_recording?ClientId={{client identity}}" callerId="client:{{client identity}}" timeout="15">
        <Client statusCallback="{{HOST}}/api/v1/calls/status_callback">{{client identity}}</Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>`